# SQL Array being returned as number, not String in ColdFusion

Tags: sql, arrays, coldfusion, cfc

In Coldfusion, I'm using a cfc that binds one select box to another (basically, choose a State from one box, the second box is populated with County names.)  The value for the County box is a 5-digit number WHICH IS FORMATTED AS TEXT (ie.  the value comes from a text field.)

The problem is that I'm finding that if the value of the selected county id starts with a '0', it's been cut off.

So I get stuff like:
ID       County
11223     A
2300      B (should be 02300)

Can someone help make sure that leading 0s are not cut off?

Here's the select boxes on the page:

```
 <!--- State Name options --->
    <b>State:</b><br />
    <cfselect bind="cfc:states.getStates()" bindonload="true" name="search_state" id="search_state" value="StateUSAbb" display="StateName">
    </cfselect><br />

  <!--- County Name options --->
    <b>County:</b><br />
    <cfselect bind="cfc:states.getCounties({search_state})" name="search_county" id="search_county" value="FIPS_County" display="CountyName">
    </cfselect>
```

I hate pasting the whole .cfc but pay attention to the latter part, particularly the cfloop which uses a cfset to populate array RESULT:

```
<cfcomponent output="false">

    <!--- Get array of media types --->
    <cffunction name="getStates" access="remote" returnType="array">
        <!--- Define variables --->
        <cfset var data="">
        <cfset var result=ArrayNew(2)>
        <cfset var i=0>

        <!--- Get data --->
        <cfquery name="data" datasource="bridges">
       SELECT DISTINCT tblLoc.StateUSAbb, lkuState.StateName
        FROM lkuState INNER JOIN tblLoc ON lkuState.FIPS_State = tblLoc.FIPS_State
        WHERE (lkuState.StateName <> 'New Brunswick')
        UNION
        SELECT '' AS StateUSAbb, ' ALL' AS StateName
        FROM lkuState
        ORDER BY StateName
        </cfquery>

        <!--- Convert results to array --->
        <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#data.RecordCount#">
            <cfset result[i][1]=data.StateUSAbb[i]>
            <cfset result[i][2]=data.StateName[i]>
        </cfloop>

        <!--- And return it --->
        <cfreturn result>
    </cffunction>

    <!--- Get counties by state --->
    <cffunction name="getCounties" access="remote" returnType="array">
        <cfargument name="stateabb" type="string" required="true">

        <!--- Define variables --->
        <cfset var data="">
        <cfset var result=ArrayNew(2)>
        <cfset var i=0>

        <!--- Get data --->
        <cfquery name="data" datasource="bridges">
        SELECT '' AS FIPS_COUNTY, ' ALL' as CountyName
        FROM lkuCnty
        UNION
        SELECT FIPS_County, CountyName
        FROM lkuCnty
        WHERE StateAbb = '#ARGUMENTS.stateabb#'
        ORDER BY CountyName
        </cfquery>

        <!--- Convert results to array --->
        <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#data.RecordCount#">
            <cfset result[i][1]=data.FIPS_County[i]>
            <cfset result[i][2]=data.CountyName[i]>
        </cfloop>

        <!--- And return it --->
        <cfreturn result>
    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: Which version of ColdFusion are you using?

Comment: This error has to do with how serialization of JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is a fixed length you can use **NumberFormat** to force leading zero's.  In general, CF is typeless so there must be some underlying conversion happening that is causing the data to get corrupt.  You might try forcing the value toString(), or to debug add something like a single quote as the first character in the column value (eg. SELECT '''' + FIPS_County, '''' + CountyName FROM lkuCnty) to see if they keep all their characters.

**[Update]**
*Based on your comments about how SQL is not returning 5 char, use this updated query to go from INT to VARCHAR with leading zeros.*

```
  SELECT DISTINCT 
    RIGHT('00000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),StateUSAbb),5), 
    lkuState.StateName
         FROM lkuState INNER JOIN tblLoc ON lkuState.FIPS_State = tblLoc.FIPS_State
         WHERE (lkuState.StateName <> 'New Brunswick')
  UNION
     SELECT '' AS StateUSAbb,
     ' ALL' AS StateName
          FROM lkuState
          ORDER BY StateName
```

Comment: I tried using cfset result[i][1]=toString(data.FIPS_County[i]).  No luck.

Comment: You need to pinpoint where the data is getting lost, in the output of the select or the assignment of the array.  Have you tried to add a single quote to see if it's coming out of SQL right?

Comment: I've been looking at this in Firebug.  When I pick a state from the select box, values in the county box are being populated such as: [25001.0,"Barnstable"].  Thus, a number.  BUT the rest of the operations on the page still work.  The next query just uses the '25001'.  If I pick a state that has county codes with leading zeros, I get stuff like: [6023.0,"Humboldt"].  At least, this is how Firebug shows it.  If I change the sql to SELECT ' ' + FIPS_County, Firebug shows values such as " 6023".  Looks like text with a leading space.  I need some logic to trim and add a 0...?

Comment: Ah... SELECT " " + FIPS_County (double quotes) pumped back [" 06023","Humboldt"].  Better!  So, I thought I'd just add a Trim as in: cfset result[i][1]=Trim(data.FIPS_County[i]).  All of the sudden, Firebug spit back stuff like [6023.0,"Humboldt"].  Numbers again.  jeez...

Comment: I think I got it.  I put the LTrim in the wrong spot.  Didn't want to set it in the array, I just put it the sql code for use on the next query that takes the County_FIPS.  ie: tblLoc.FIPS_County = LTrim(<cfqueryparam value="#search_county#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR"/>).   I THINK this works now.

Comment: Thanks for the update above but you have this code for the wrong portion of my sql statement.  The issue isn't with the code for the StateUSAbb, it's with retrieving the counties as in County_FIPS.  In any case, I may try to apply it to the proper section but as I have it working at the moment using the trim (see above comment), I may just stick w/it.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

append a space to the end of the number, then CF will treat it as a string and no leading 0 will be chopped.

simple workaround: `<cfset result[i][1]=data.StateUSAbb[i] & " ">`

btw, you know that query object is supported for populating `cfselect` right?  So you don't even need the loop.  You can do the same workaround but in SQL inside your cfquery

**UPDATE:** anyway, the idea is that if u want to preserve the leading 0 and keep using CF's built in serializeJSON() or calling the cfc remote method in JSON style (which will internally invoke serializeJSON(), you can append a space so CF will treat it as a string and leading 0 will be preserved.  If your script somehow must need "012345" with no trailing space, then look for another JSON seralizer from riaforge or cflib.

Comment: Dude.  didn't work.  I changed the line to this: cfset result[i][1]=data.FIPS_County[i] & " "  (you appended the empty quote to the wrong variable).  Anyway, it didn't have any effect at all on the results.  Same thing happens.

Comment: So you want data.FIPS_County to be formatted as string right? take a look at the JSON in firebug, see if FIPS_County is formatted like FIPS_County:"0123 ", or FIPS_County:123

Comment: When I have debugging on in CF, it shows Parameter #2(CF_SQL_VARCHAR) = 25011 for FIPS_County that doesn't have a leading 0.  and Parameter #2(CF_SQL_VARCHAR) = 6023 where it should (06023). 
I'm not sure if I'm looking in the right place in Firebug (Net > XHR > Get States.cfc?method=getCounties.....):  under "Response" it just shows [[" "," ALL"]].  This would be the first part of the SQL (the rest is union'd).  But I see the same thing even for a county w/out a leading 0.  So maybe I'm not looking in the right place?

Comment: When I have debugging on in CF, it shows Parameter #2(CF_SQL_VARCHAR) = 25011 for FIPS_County that doesn't have a leading 0.  and Parameter #2(CF_SQL_VARCHAR) = 6023 where it should (06023). 
I'm not sure if I'm looking in the right place in Firebug (Net > All > Post..>  search_county 6023

Comment: Thanks but your advice w/the JSON serializer is a bit beyond me so I wouldn't know how to implement that suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You're sure the data returned from your query is a text string which contains the leading zero, rather than just the integer value?  Regardless, I think Zachary's suggestion of NumberFormat(x, "00000") is the way to go.

Comment: Not sure why it wouldn't be a text string.  After all, the fieldtype is a number (double). And the value being used is plugged into another cfquery with a cfqueryparm tag of cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" and it works fine other than the fact that the leading 0 isn't there.  Would love just a bit more help in implementing this suggestion but I'm concerned.  Why would I want to format it as a number?  Will that change it to a number from a string?  Again, it needs to be a string.  thx.

Comment: also tried cfset result[i][1]= NumberFormat(data.FIPS_County[i], "00000".   Same result.  fine for County_FIPS w/out a leading zero.  No good for others with a leading 0.